# nodejs cookie not persist from request.post to a follow up request.get call

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, cookies

Using NodeJS, opn to open up a protected web page in a default browser after login. here is the code break down.

```
var loginActionUrl = "http://example.com/Logon.do";

    var protectedPageUrl = "http://example.com/protected_page.html";

    request.post({
        url: loginActionUrl,
        jar: jar.getJar(),
        followAllRedirects: false,
        body: 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password

        }, function (err, res, body) {
            //enter code here
            request.get({
                 url:protectedPageurl,
                 method: 'get',
                 jar: jar.getJar()
            }, function(err, res, body) {
                // todo 2
            } 

    });
```

SO, from the post call, I get set-cookie in response headers.

```
'set-cookie':
   [ 'X-Uaa-Csrf=JFrlPA; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; HttpOnly',
     'X-Uaa-Csrf=RmXmOa; Expires=Mon, 16-Oct-2017 18:24:22 GMT; HttpOnly',
     'SESSION=b0536096-e184-4f42-a68f-ff8f58802adc; Path=/Logon/; HttpOnly' ]
```

then, the set-cookie info get lost in the follow up http.get call, you can't find it from the new response header, see below

```
'set-cookie': [ 'JSESSIONID=8CB721B97EE3C07FAD481A56A84B4D82.protectedpage-111-22-333-44; Path=/ProtectedPage; HttpOnly' ]
```

I am using cookieJar to get/set the cookie, I am set followAllRedirects to false, so, I am expecting, the cookie will carry over to the next call. but, it is not.

any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 1):

fixed this issue by setting up a personal cookieJar

```
// init personal jar 
var cookiejar = request.jar();
request.defaults({jar:cookieJar});

// reset the jar
cookieJar = request.jar()

// if want to add extra to the cookie,
cookieJar.setCookie('key=value')
```

Comment: what the heck does this mean :P